# Language issue with Excel Formulas generated in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have a spreadsheet which I have developed.

It works absolutely fine, however part of the vba code is it generates formulas based on data and selections the user makes.

(nothing too fancy an example of one of the formulas is

```
=(TEXT(EDATE([@[First Payment Date]],12*[@[Mortgage Length]]),""dd/mm/yyyy"")- 
TEXT(""01/01/""&YEAR(EDATE([@[First Payment Date]],
12*[@[Mortgage Length]])),""dd/mm/yyyy""))/(DATE(YEAR([@[First Payment Date]]),12,31)-
DATE(YEAR([@[First Payment Date]]),1,1)+1)*[@[Customer Equity Amount Per Year]]
```

As you can see it uses various formulas like Date, Year etc.

And as mentioned before this works fine, and if I run the code then hand the sheet to a colleague (who is based in Germany the formulas update automatically to German for him)

However if he runs the code with new data, the formulas appear in English in the sheet and then error (because his german version of excel doesn't recognise them)

Am I going to have to update my code to check the language of the current user and whether to output the formulas in English or German?

Or is there another solution to this?

As requested in comments the way I'm applying formula to my table is with this code:

```
Set DealTable = shDbDealInfo.ListObjects("Deal_Information_Table")

If NewDealLine = 1 Then
    shDbDealInfo.Cells(8, "A") = "a"
End If

With DealTable
    
    
    .ListColumns("Customer Equity Amount Per Year").DataBodyRange(NewDealLine) = "=[@[Property Value]]*[@[Customer Equity %]]"
    .ListColumns("Customer Purchase Cost Per Year").DataBodyRange(NewDealLine) = shCalculators.Range("Calc_Customer_Purcase_Cost")
    .ListColumns("Bank Guarantee Cost Year").DataBodyRange(NewDealLine) = "=IF(Forecast_Start_Date=[@[First Payment Date]],1,ROUNDUP(YEARFRAC(Forecast_Start_Date,[@[First Payment Date]]),0))"
    .ListColumns("First Year Partial Equity").DataBodyRange(NewDealLine) = "=((TEXT(""31/12/""&YEAR([@[First Payment Date]]),""dd/mm/yyyy"")-TEXT([@[First Payment Date]],""dd/mm/yyyy""))+1)/(DATE(YEAR([@[First Payment Date]]),12,31)-DATE(YEAR([@[First Payment Date]]),1,1)+1)*[@[Customer Equity Amount Per Year]]"
    .ListColumns("First Year Partial Purchase Cost").DataBodyRange(NewDealLine) = "=((TEXT(""31/12/""&YEAR([@[First Payment Date]]),""dd/mm/yyyy"")-TEXT([@[First Payment Date]],""dd/mm/yyyy""))+1)/(DATE(YEAR([@[First Payment Date]]),12,31)-DATE(YEAR([@[First Payment Date]]),1,1)+1)*[@[Customer Purchase Cost Per Year]]"
    .ListColumns("First Month Partial Equity").DataBodyRange(NewDealLine) = "=(((TEXT(DAY(EOMONTH([@[First Payment Date]],0))&""/""&MONTH([@[First Payment Date]])&""/""&YEAR([@[First Payment Date]]),""DD/MM/YYYY"")-[@[First Payment Date]])+1)/((TEXT(""31/12/""&YEAR([@[First Payment Date]]),""dd/mm/yyyy"")-TEXT([@[First Payment Date]],""dd/mm/yyyy""))+1))*[@[First Year Partial Equity]]"
    .ListColumns("First Month Partial Purchase Cost").DataBodyRange(NewDealLine) = "=(((TEXT(DAY(EOMONTH([@[First Payment Date]],0))&""/""&MONTH([@[First Payment Date]])&""/""&YEAR([@[First Payment Date]]),""DD/MM/YYYY"")-[@[First Payment Date]])+1)/((TEXT(""31/12/""&YEAR([@[First Payment Date]]),""dd/mm/yyyy"")-TEXT([@[First Payment Date]],""dd/mm/yyyy""))+1))*[@[First Year Partial Purchase Cost]]"
    .ListColumns("Final Year Partial Equity").DataBodyRange(NewDealLine) = "=(TEXT(EDATE([@[First Payment Date]],12*[@[Mortgage Length]]),""dd/mm/yyyy"")- TEXT(""01/01/""&YEAR(EDATE([@[First Payment Date]],12*[@[Mortgage Length]])),""dd/mm/yyyy""))/(DATE(YEAR([@[First Payment Date]]),12,31)-DATE(YEAR([@[First Payment Date]]),1,1)+1)*[@[Customer Equity Amount Per Year]]"
    .ListColumns("Final Year Partial Purchase Cost").DataBodyRange(NewDealLine) = "=(TEXT(EDATE([@[First Payment Date]],12*[@[Mortgage Length]]),""dd/mm/yyyy"")- TEXT(""01/01/""&YEAR(EDATE([@[First Payment Date]],12*[@[Mortgage Length]])),""dd/mm/yyyy""))/(DATE(YEAR([@[First Payment Date]]),12,31)-DATE(YEAR([@[First Payment Date]]),1,1)+1)*[@[Customer Purchase Cost Per Year]]"
    .ListColumns("Final Month Partial Equity").DataBodyRange(NewDealLine) = "=(((EDATE([@[First Payment Date]],12*[@[Mortgage Length]]))-TEXT(""01/""&MONTH(EDATE([@[First Payment Date]],12*[@[Mortgage Length]]))&""/""&YEAR(EDATE([@[First Payment Date]],12*[@[Mortgage Length]])),""DD/MM/YYYY""))/((TEXT(""31/12/""&YEAR(EDATE([@[First Payment Date]],12*[@[Mortgage Length]])),""dd/mm/yyyy"")-TEXT(EDATE([@[First Payment Date]],12*[@[Mortgage Length]]),""dd/mm/yyyy""))+1))*[@[First Year Partial Equity]]"
    .ListColumns("Final Month Partial Purchase Cost").DataBodyRange(NewDealLine) = "=(((EDATE([@[First Payment Date]],12*[@[Mortgage Length]]))-TEXT(""01/""&MONTH(EDATE([@[First Payment Date]],12*[@[Mortgage Length]]))&""/""&YEAR(EDATE([@[First Payment Date]],12*[@[Mortgage Length]])),""DD/MM/YYYY""))/((TEXT(""31/12/""&YEAR(EDATE([@[First Payment Date]],12*[@[Mortgage Length]])),""dd/mm/yyyy"")-TEXT(EDATE([@[First Payment Date]],12*[@[Mortgage Length]]),""dd/mm/yyyy""))+1))*[@[First Year Partial Purchase Cost]]"

End With
```

Comment: Exactly how are you setting the formulas?   If you apply english formulas using VBA they should auto-update if the local language setting is different.

Comment: As @Tim Williams asked above, are the formulas in discussion written by code? If so, please edit your question and show us that part. Then, is it only about formulas in cells, or cells Validation formulas, too?

Comment: Apologies, I didn't include the code originally since it was working. I've added it now, There are more fields than I've shown, but didn't want to make it a huge code snippet.

As mentioned this works fine on my machine (english) and when colleague opens the sheet after I save it, Excel updates the Formulas to German. But if he runs the code, then it inserts the formulas to the tables in English, which then show errors for him.

Comment: Please, try **`telling to Excel`** that you input a formula. I mean, try using `.ListColumns("Customer Equity Amount Per Year").DataBodyRange(NewDealLine).Formula = "=[@[Property Value]]*[@[Customer Equity %]]"` Please, see the `Formula` property before the equal sign... I meant, that VBA takes the string as what it is (a string) and then **Excel tries evaluating** and no too much meaning for German language...

Comment: Thanks! that seems to have done the trick
Going to do more testing, but looks good for now

Comment: You always (if possible) should use the correct cell property. If Excel does not know what data you try entering, it try guessing. Only in English the string looking as a formula has a clear meaning. You may try in the German localization the next checking way: Select a cell having such a formula then, write a single code line in a new sub `Debug.print ActiveCell.FormulaLocale`. If it is able to convert the string in English formula (which looks probable to me, without being able to test...) you will see the German formula version. You can try `ActiveCell.Formula = ActiveCell.FormulaLocale`...

Answer (score 0):

Instead of implicitly using default `.Value` property of Range object like in your case

```
With DealTable
  .ListColumns("Customer Equity Amount Per Year").DataBodyRange(NewDealLine) = "=..." 
End With
```

you would maybe use explicitly declared `.FormulaLocal` property.

```
With DealTable
  .ListColumns("Customer Equity Amount Per Year").DataBodyRange(NewDealLine).FormulaLocal = "=..." 
End With
```

Comment: You absolutely do **not** want the `FormulaLocal` property since that will expect the formula string to be in the user's language, which is exactly the problem at hand. ;)

Comment: @Rory. Well, in this particular case, when developer uses English formulas and sends such workbook to colleagues in german environment, I agree with your point.  

On the other side if the developer would use German formulas, he needs ``FormulaLocal`` otherwise in English environment it would throw an error. So, thanks for correcting me.